# How to access a variable in python script from another python script class avoiding circular module import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

Here is the basic structure of my code

```
#master_la.py

global dname

class CommonSetup:
    def get_device:
        dname="BNV023"
```

And I have the script where I want to access the variable `dname`

```
#salve_la.py
from foo.bar import master_la
class LaUtils:
    name = master_la.dname
```

This code is not working. Can I know how to resolve this ?
with this coded I'm getting error like

```
AttributeError: module 'foo.bar.master_la' has no attribute 'dname'
```

Comment: A module should not be dependent on the variables in the script that imports it. You should pass `dname` as a parameter to the `__init__()` method of `LaUtils`

Comment: Ignoring syntax issues, you have `dname="BNV023"` is defined at runtime and so is not available when `salve_la.py` is imported.

Comment: Also, `dname` is a local variable, not a global variable.

Comment: @Barmar I changed the code here to make the variable global and change import structure , but still getting the mentioned error.

Comment: This is not the right organization.  The "slave" modules need to stand alone.  If they need information from the master, then that information needs to be passed in as parameters.

Comment: @mac That was jsut an "also". It doesn't solve the problem because a module can't refer to variables in the caller.

Comment: As someone else pointed out, the variable isn't even set until you call `get_device()`. How do you expect it to be used when the class is first being defined?

Comment: There is no global variable `dname` defined anywhere in `master_la.py`.

Comment: @mac you did not make any global variable `dname` with your changes. This is quite crucial to understand.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I did define with `global dname` in master_la.py

Comment: No, no you didn't. Which is *why* you get the error. If you *had* then that error wouldn't occur. Where do you think you assign to a global variable in `master_la.py`? `global dname` does not define a global variable, it is a directive that *any assignment in that scope to that variable should be global*. Of course, that is in the global scope, so it is completely pointless. Regardless, it doesn't define any variable. You very clearly are defining a class variable. I think you are fundamentally confused about scope and classes.

Comment: so, to assign to a global variable `dname`, you either need an assignment in the global scope, or an assignment in some other scope where the `global dname` directive is used

Answer (score 0):

Here's the right way to organize this.  Remember that LaUtils doesn't need that value until you create an object of that class.

```
from lib.foo.bar.api.foo.slave_la import LaUtils 

class CommonSetup:
    def get_device(self):
        dname="BNV023"
        self.la = LaUtils(dname)
```

#slave_la.py

```
class LaUtils:
    def __init__(self, dname):
        self.name = dname
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is `self.la` mean  here ?

Comment: The whole point of the `LaUtils` class is so you can create objects of that type.  You don't need that `dname` until you actually create those objects.  I'm just showing that creation.